# Ругается компилятор

Tags: c++, массивы

Ошибка компиляции на `cols` во вложенном цикле:

```cpp
void FillArr(int arr[], const int ROW, const int COL) {
    for (int cols = 0, num = 0; cols < COL; cols++) {
        for (int rows = 0; rows < ROW; rows++, num++) {
            arr[rows][cols] = num;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: У вас передается в функцию **одномерный** массив, а обращаетесь вы с ним, как с двумерным...

Comment: У вас передается в функцию опциональный **указатель** на 0 или более элементов типа `int`, наверное тут подразумевается, что он указывает на массив ROW x COL элементов, соответственно вам надо считать индекс.

Comment: @Harry я исправил код, но теперь ошибку на третью скобку выдаёт   void FillAr ( int arr [] [])  На третью квадратную

Comment: Нельзя так просто передать в функцию двухмерный массив не константного размера. Лучше используйте вместо него одномерный размера `ROW * COL`.

Comment: Потому что при передаче двумерного массива именно в таком виде первая размерность должна быть указана. **Как я думаю** (*нужную информацию вы в вопросе не привели*), вам нужен первый вариант, но обращение не `arr[rows][cols]`, а `arr[rows*COLS+cols]`.

Comment: @Harry Можете посоветовать, как подтянуть c++? Я очень хочу в нём "шарить"

Comment: @Harry а можете новичку разжевать вот эту строчку, почему именно так? **arr[rows*COL+cols] = num;**     Почему моё обращение не подходит? **arr[rows][cols]**

Comment: @ГеннадийСамойлов, потому что во втором случае, вы по сути пишите то же самое, но перекладываете работу по превращению **arr[rows][cols]** в **arr[rows*COL+cols]** на компилятор, а он в этот момент не знает, где ему **COL** взять.

Comment: Я даже не прочитал в чем проблема, но по поводу того, что компилятор ругается, я вас поздравляю,

Comment: На Си (gcc), но не в С++ вы могли бы написать вот так: `void FillArr(const int COL, int arr[][COL], const int ROW)` (нужно передать COL до его использования в описании массива) и обращаться к элементам `arr[rows][cols]`. / Выводы делайте сами

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(ответа нет, комментарии есть, так что попробую написать ответ)* Вы пытаетесь обратиться к одномерному массиву как к двумерному:

```cpp
// здесь int arr[] тоже самое, что и int *arr

void FillArr(int arr[], const int ROW, const int COL) {
    ...
    arr[rows][cols] = ...;
    ...
}
```

Из-за чего компилятор не понимает ваших намерений и выдает ошибку компиляции.

Исправить проблему можно двумя способами, в зависимости от того, что у вас представляет из себя двумерный массив.

1. Изменить сигнатуру метода, то есть сделать в функции из `arr` двумерный массив. Использовать, если входной массив был создан как `int *arr[y]` (y -> количество строк) или `int **arr`.

```cpp
//           int *arr[],

void FillArr(int **arr, const int ROW, const int COL) {
    for (int cols = 0, num = 0; cols < COL; cols++) {
        for (int rows = 0; rows < ROW; rows++, num++) {
            arr[rows][cols] = num;
        }
    }
}
```

2. Использовать *математику*, чтобы превратить обращение к одномерному массиву так, будто бы это двумерный массив. Использовать, если входной массив был создан как `int arr[x]`, `int *arr`; еще можно ожидать `int arr[y][x]`, однако придется будет преобразовывать его в `int*` -> `reinterpret_cast<int*>(arr)` при вызове.

```cpp
//           int arr[],

void FillArr(int *arr, const int ROW, const int COL) {
    for (int cols = 0, num = 0; cols < COL; cols++) {
        for (int rows = 0; rows < ROW; rows++, num++) {
            // rows * COL позволит нам перепрыгнуть определённое количество
            // элементов (равняещееся количеству колонок в двумерном
            // массиве умноженное на количество пройденный строчек),
            // а суммирование просто сделает отступ от этого прыжка.
            // Прыжком мы дойдем до нужной строки, а отступ
            // позволит получить элемент в этой строке.

            arr[rows * COL + cols] = num;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Проверял свои суждения на `gcc 8.3.0; gcc -xc++ -lstdc++ -shared-libgcc -std=C++14`.